# Redundant use of local information in robot_localization when fusing local and global data?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using robot_localization to fuse both local and global sensor information for a 2d differential drive robot.
More precisely odometry, imu and when available global pose information are fused.

My configuration basically follows this tutorials:
[ros-sensor-fusion-tutorial](https://github.com/methylDragon/ros-sensor-fusion-tutorial/blob/master/01%20-%20ROS%20and%20Sensor%20Fusion%20Tutorial.md)

According to that I have set up two separated r_l nodes for local and global fusion, with the local fusion node only taking odom and imu and the global one additionally using the global pose information. The local fusion node also provides the (fused) `odom->base_link` tf.

However, I am wondering whether the proposed configuration may lead to redundant use of the local sensor information, which should be avoided in sensor fusion as this may lead to biased results.
As far as I understand, the global r_l node takes the raw sensor msgs but first transforms them into the world frame (map_frame) implicitly using the `odom->base_link` tf provided by the local r_l node.

Does not this mean, that the local information is used twice in the global r_l node, once in form of the original data and once as the fused `odom->base_link` tf?

If this is not the case, can someone please point me in the right direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332605/redundant-use-of-local-information-in-robot_localization-when-fusing-local-and-global-data?/) by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 218 on 2019-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> As far as I understand, the global r_l node takes the raw sensor msgs but first transforms them into the world frame (map_frame) implicitly using the odom->base_link tf provided by the local r_l node.

In general, this isn't accurate.

In the sensor fusion nodes in `r_l`, the assumptions are generally

- All velocity and acceleration data is in the robot's body (e.g., *base_link*) frame, **or** there is a transform from the sensor's frame to that body frame **that does not "pass through" the `world_frame`->`base_link_frame` transform**. So, e.g., you should not have velocities reported in the `map` frame that are getting fused in a filter.
- All pose data is in a world-fixed frame that can be transformed to your `world_frame` without passing through the `world_frame`->`base_link` frame transform. So, for example, you should not have pose data that is relative to *base_link* being fused.

Internally, the filter first transforms velocity data into your `base_link_frame`. Then, when it passes through the kinematic model, the model itself is transforming it into the world frame you specify. But velocity data, when fused in the *map* frame EKF, does **not** pass through the *odom*->*base_link* transform.

Another thing to keep in mind is that, even if the velocity data *were* to pass through the *odom*->*base_link* transform, it is effectively meaningless. The *map* frame EKF is actually generating the *map*->*base_link* transform, but since `tf` doesn't permit reparenting, we need to compute map->odom so that we can make a chain:

`T_map_odom = T_map_base_link * T_odom_base_link^-1`

Now we have *map*->*odom*->*base_link*. But you can change `T_odom_base_link` to be anything, and *map*->*base_link* will remain the same, since we're constantly updating `T_map_odom`. So data transformed from *base_link* to *map* will always be consistent, since we're keeping track of the transform between *map* and *odom*.

In any case, you can generally consider the EKFs to be completely separate. The only exception is if you try to, e.g., fuse *pose* data inputs that are in the *odom* frame into the *map* frame EKF.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2019-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2